# Is it necessary to exclude node_modules when src is set in tsconfig.json?

Tags: typescript

Most boilerplate I find includes `"exclude": ["node_modules"]` but this property appears to be unnecessary given `"include": ["src"]` (`node_modules` being outside of `src`). Am I missing something?

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not necessary because

1. `"node_modules"` is one of the patterns excluded by default
2. `"exclude"` specifies an array of filenames or patterns that should be skipped when resolving `"include"` (and as you pointed out it is out of `src` anyway)

[Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exclude)